# Convert string to character code array

Tags: .net, vb.net, arrays

I want to convert characters like,

```
Dim Str as String = **Chr(198) & Chr(233) & "ÿ¤"**
```

Now I want to convert back `Str` to its character codes.

I am using this code:

```
Dim Bt(Str.Length - 1) As Byte
For i = 0 To Bt.Length - 1
    Bt(i) = Asc (Str(i)) ' Using the Asc() function
Next
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [LINQ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query):

```
Dim bt = Str.ToCharArray().Select(Function(x) Convert.ToByte(x)).ToArray()
```